# C# mysql database. how to pass a very big dataset to table very fast?

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, dataset

I have a very big dataset read from XML (2gb)

I want to put the table of datasets to db.

I currently traverse the dataset tables and inset to db tables but this takes forever will not finish.

is there a very fast way of it to copy the dataset table into the database table?

I guess some store procedure can take the table as input and process it.

Thanks a lot in advance,

Comment: Don't assume a stored procedure will be fast. Have you tuned your [mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83125/mysql-any-way-to-import-a-huge-32-gb-sql-dump-faster) for bulk importing? If you can split the xml into multiple threads that will help.

Comment: How are you reading the file?

Comment: Is this one-time operation? If not - ask your DB admin on what type of input can be bulk-imported and change input instead (if you are DB admin - search/ask on [dba.se]).

Comment: This shall be quite rutine work.
I am the DB admin. 
it is a localdatabase on my PC i will carry it to a server once the program finished. 

reading file is just simple : 
            string xmlFile = "<mypath>\\export_lncell.xml";

            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataSet.ReadXml(xmlFile, XmlReadMode.InferSchema);

Comment: How come there is no way that we can not just pass the DataTable to a table in Mysql ?

reading and writing row to row takes me 20 hours with the current HW i have.

But to export a dataset to an excel file takes 2 min. and this excel file can be created as a table with import with 2 min as well.

But i do not want to do manual work.